# How to continue if snprintf stops in the middle of a format specifier?

Tags: c, printf

The `snprintf` function is perfect when the output buffer may not be big enough to hold the formatted string. But if a call to `snprintf` stopped due to insufficient buffer length, how to continue printing to another buffer?

```
char buf1[16] = {0};
char buf2[16] = {0};
int n = snprintf(buf1, sizeof buf1, "Lorem ipsum %d dolor sit", 123456);
assert(strcmp(buf1, "Lorem ipsum 123") == 0);  // ok

// Insert solution here

assert(strcmp(buf2, "456 dolor sit") == 0);  // expected result
```

P.S. I'm not hellbound on `snprintf`, any solution confined to the standard C library will do.

Comment: Did you ever examine the `n` value?

Comment: @MooingDuck Of course, that's why I put it in the snippet. I know the idiom to first call `snprintf` with `n = 0` to determine length, then allocate sufficiently sized buffer, then do the real print. My question is whether there is a way to resume from where `snprintf` stopped without allocating an extra buffer.

Answer (score 3):

no.  `snprintf` is stateless, it can't simply "resume" where it stopped.  The closest would be to allocate a bigger buffer, print the entire message to that, then strcpy the desired substring to the target buffer.

```
char buf1[16] = {0};
char buf2[16] = {0};
int n = snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1), "Lorem ipsum %d dolor sit", 123456);

if (n > 15) {
    char* t = malloc(n+1);
    if (t) {
        n = snprintf(t, n, "Lorem ipsum %d dolor sit", 123456);
        strncpy(buf2, t+sizeof(buf1)-1, sizeof(buf2)-1);
        free(t);
    }
    //might fail the subsequent assert if malloc failed
}

assert(strcmp(buf1, "Lorem ipsum 123") == 0);  // ok
assert(strcmp(buf2, "456 dolor sit") == 0);  // expected result
```

Comment: Missing test against failure of `malloc`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks.  I'm used to C++ where I don't have to check in that way.

Comment: This should include code to null-terminate `buf2` (this specific string fits in the buffer but there would be problems if a longer string is used)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: And this is why we invented C++

Comment: @MattMcNabb: In the best case, the null-termination-code added is harmless. In the expected case, it's silent data loss, a hard to find bug. Anyway, `strncpy` is simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Deduplicator in the general case it causes undefined behaviour because `strcmp(buf2` will be called with a non-null-terminated string. If silent data loss is a problem then you need an explicit check and action path to take if the string is too long, regardless of which tool you use of getting the data into `buf2`.

Answer (score 2):

Read documentation of [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html). It returns the total number of needed characters (and you could even invoke it with a `NULL` buffer of size 0 to get the number of needed characters first). And on Linux with Gnu [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), you might also use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html).

So you might code:

```
 int nbc = snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1),
    "Lorem ipsum %d dolor sit", 123456);
 if (nbc<sizeof(buf1)) 
    behappywith(buf1);
 else {
    memset(buf2, 0, sizeof(buf2));
    char* dynbuf = malloc(nbc+1);
    if (!dynbuf) { perror("malloc dynbuf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    snprintf(dynbuf, nbc+1,
             "Lorem ipsum %d dolor sit", 123456);
    strncpy(buf2, dynbuf+sizeof(buf1), sizeof(buf2));
    buf2[sizeof(buf2)-1] = '\0';
    free (dynbuf);
    behappywithboth(buf1,buf2);
 }
```

In practice, it is better to call `snprintf` with a reasonably large enough buffer -to *usually* avoid calling `malloc` then `snprintf`  a *second* time- (so 16 bytes is not enough, but in your case 64 bytes would have been reasonable), and redo it only in rare cases. If possible, use `asprintf`

Comment: `buf2` needs null termination code in case the string did not fit

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pipe, use `fprintf` to write the whole string in there and use a second thread to read from the pipe with as small chunks as you like. This way `fprintf` function will block and save the state until you dispatch the data.

The implementation obviously won't fit in your template, but if your data is too big to fit in a single memory buffer, you'll have to generate and dispatch data at the same time. Otherwise, just allocate a single sufficiently large buffer like Mooing Duck suggested.